# ManifoldJS to package a Windows EdgeExtension, but the result is empty

Tags: microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension, manifoldjs

I follow the guide to package the extension in this guide:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/guides/packaging/using-manifoldjs-to-package-extensions.

The sample extension is in download from:
https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/MicrosoftEdge-Extensions-Demos/tree/master/color_changer

I use the tool: ManifoldJS.

but the result of the target folder is empty.

Comment: I try to follow the steps mentioned in the documentation and I also get the similar result as you. We are looking in to this issue. We will try to make further tests with it and try to find the root cause for this issue. We will try to inform you as soon as we found any helpful information. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: thank you. look forward to getting the progress from you.

Answer (score 0):

We confirmed that this is a known issue of manifoldjs-edgeextension, please check below link for detail information, still no updates yet.

https://github.com/pwa-builder/manifoldjs-edgeextension/issues/19

As a workaround, **NodeJS version 8** works good for this extension, tested it and got the outputs.